# What does it mean when a symbol appears multiple times in nm output?

Tags: shared-libraries, nm

I ran `nm` on `libtorch`, a popular machine learning library to search for a function called `tensorTypeIdToBackend`. The output starts like this

```
nm -C libtorch.so | grep tensorTypeIdToBackend
00000000031d2b00 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
000000000335c240 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003a40e20 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003b6cf60 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003b8d0b0 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003b9afe0 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003c007b0 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003c35aa0 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003c5ee40 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003c78e20 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003cc1800 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003d2bf10 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003d7c4a0 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003d88fc0 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003d96f90 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003dad910 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003dde2d0 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003e0c360 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000003f49940 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000004054450 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000005a32d00 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000005c51070 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000005d42cd0 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000005e2f350 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000005f298d0 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000005f48460 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000005f8d630 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000005fa31f0 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000006388eb0 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
00000000064349d0 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
0000000006826160 t c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)
000000000fdd6780 r c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)::__func__
000000000fdd7630 r c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)::__func__
000000000fdd8390 r c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)::__func__
000000000fdd8e30 r c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)::__func__
000000000fdd98d0 r c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)::__func__
000000000fddb450 r c10::tensorTypeIdToBackend(c10::TensorTypeId)::__func__
```

What does it mean that the function is repeated so many times, sometimes in the text/code section, and sometimes in the read only data section? And then sometimes with a `__func__` suffix? I would have expected to see it only once, at the particular address which it is defined.